# How to install Java 7 EE SDK download as .sh file for Mac OSX

Tags: java, macos, java-ee-7

I am new to developing Java on Mac OSX. I wanted to download the Java 7 EE SDK so I could both desktop/mobile/enterprise development with Java. The download file is `.sh` (specifically `java_ee_sdk-7-jdk7-macosx-x64`) which I am not familiar with. The Java 7 SE SDK is a `.dmg` file which is the format I expected for the Enterprise Edition instead of the `.sh` file.

1. Why are the SE and EE editions different file formats? (`.sh` vs `.dmg`)
2. How do I install the Enterprise Edition being that it is a `.sh`
   file?

*Note: Currently the only JRE I have installed on the Mac is the Apple version which I understand has been deprecated.

Comment: You honestly took the time to whine about my question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run it at the command line.

From the install manual: [Java Platform, Enterprise Edition 7 SDK - Installation Instructions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/documentation/javaee7sdk-install-1957708.html#install)

> **Solaris, Linux, and Mac OS X systems**:
>
> - If necessary, grant execute
>   permissions to the distribution file: chmod +x ./
>   distribution-filename
> - At the command prompt, type: sh ./
>   distribution-filename

For future reference a *.sh file is a [shell script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script). You can inspect the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) (`#!`) at the first line of the file to see what shell should be used to interpret the script. In the case of the JavaEE 7 installer the shebang is `#!/bin/sh` which indicates a [Bourne compatible shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_Shell) should be used.

Comment: Thank you! Any idea why the SE and EE versions are different formats?

Comment: @webworm Probably so they could use one installer for all unix-like platforms.

Comment: Different teams produce the SE and EE SDKs. The EE SDK doesn't need OS-specific configuration for the various Unix-like OSes, unlike SE.

Comment: When I attempt to run this, it says it needs the DISPLAY variable set  - what do I need to set it to? `a12-macmini-02:Downloads rdavis$ ./java_ee_sdk-7-jdk7-macosx-x64-ml.sh
This program requires DISPLAY environment variable to be set.
Please re-run after assigning an appropriate value to DISPLAY.`

Comment: Be aware that the "JavaEE SDK" is basically just a lie; its a bundle package of the JDK, Glassfish community and some documentation all of which you can install/download separately. JEE is only a specification, you are free to just install the JDK and any JEE container of your choosing (JBoss, Weblogic, TomEE, ...).

Answer (score 7):

Found a solution in this link:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63381/installing-glassfish-on-mountain-lion

Tried the command `export DISPLAY=:0` and it skipped the "This Program requires..." message.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 7):

`glassfish-3.1.2.2-unix.sh` requires `DISPLAY` environment variable to be set.
Please re-run after assigning an appropriate value to `DISPLAY`.

`export DISPLAY=:0`
`chmod +x java_ee_sdk-7-jdk7-macosx-x64-ml.sh`
`./java_ee_sdk-7-jdk7-macosx-x64-ml.sh`