# Java - JDK Installation on Mac OS X 10.9.5

Tags: java, macos

I'm attempting to learn Java, and I found a neat tutorial to show me the ropes. Except, all of the JDK installation process is shown in Windows, and I use a Mac.

It asks for me to copy the path/location of the bin folder on my machine (and I know where it is), go to the Start menu, go through properties and advanced system settings, go through Environment Variables, plug in the location, and something else.

I don't know how all of this will translate to Mac, but I'd really appreciate some help.

(I use JDK 1.8.0_45)

Comment: don't do that, with mac there is a dmg available of JDK install it straight, it will take care of PATH and installation

Comment: so it does it automatically?

Comment: @blootannery  try to check this post as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794055/how-to-install-java-7-ee-sdk-download-as-sh-file-for-mac-osx/20773158#20773158

Answer (score 0):

Here's the official Oracle documentation:
[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html][1]

It's a pretty simple process if you follow step by step.

Here's where you can download the JDK for Mac on Oracle's website:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html